# Sequelize.js save() result

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

the code like this:

```
(function () {
    var tag = models.Tag.build({ create_time: new Date(), is_hot: '0', is_lock: '0', name: 'Nodejs' });
    tag.save();
    console.log(tag.dataValues);
    tag.name = "npm";
    tag.save();
    console.log(tag.dataValues);
    tag = models.Tag.build({ create_time: new Date(), is_hot: '0', is_lock: '0', name: 'webpack' });
    tag.save();
    console.log(tag.dataValues);
})();
```

the result is: 
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCEqc.png)

in my first eys,the result maybe:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `t_tag` (`id`,`name`,`create_time`,`is_hot`,`is_lock`,`is_delete`) VALUES (NULL,'Nodejs','2016-12-23 03:09:23','0','0','0');
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `t_tag` (`id`,`name`,`create_time`,`is_hot`,`is_lock`,`is_delete`) VALUES (NULL,'npm','2016-12-23 03:09:23','0','0','0');
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `t_tag` (`id`,`name`,`create_time`,`is_hot`,`is_lock`,`is_delete`) VALUES (NULL,'webpack','2016-12-23 03:09:26','0','0','0');
```

what causes that ?
why the "npm" record insert double time?

Comment: to avoid that just build another model for `npm`

Comment: yeah，is can solve the problem。but why the **npm**insert double time

Comment: when you `tag.name = "npm";` it doesn't really change the value of column `name` in your build Tag and remember you try `tag.save()` again which it will just insert the previous value again that's why it insert twice

Comment: when the code like `(function () {
    var tag = models.Tag.build({ create_time: new Date(), is_hot: '0', is_lock: '0', name: 'Nodejs' });
    console.log(tag.dataValues);
    tag.save();
    tag.name = "npm";
})();`, it also insert the `npm`. TnT

Answer (score 5):

Sequelize functions run asynchronously. `save` returns a promise, which you can `.then()` off of to ensure that you're picking up after the SQL call has gone through. Since you're not doing that, the first `save` hasn't persisted by the time you change `tag.name` to "npm" and therefore "npm" is inserted twice (notice how all three `console.log` calls execute before anything else happens -- this is another sign that you're not doing async properly). Fix your flow control to work with the promises and you won't have this problem.

Comment: you mean: when the code run `tag.name ="npm"`, the first `tag.save()` didn't complete? Is it right?

Comment: Yes, the first `tag.save()` went through _after_ `tag.name = "npm"` because you didn't wait for the asynchronous save to finish. The examples in the Sequelize docs show how to use `model.save().then(do the next thing)`.